# Slicing for multiple asserts

Tags: frama-c, program-slicing

Is it possible to use `Frama-C`'s slicing plugin to slice for more than one assertion?

E.g. given the following code:

```
#include "assert.h"

int main() {
    double a=3;
    double b=4;
    b=a+b;
    double c=123;

//@ assert(b>=0);

    double d=a/b;
    c=a;

//@ assert(c==0);

    if (a<b)
        a=c;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to get the slice for both assertions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `-slice-assert main` will choose as slicing criterion all the assertions of function `main`. In fact, you can't directly choose to slice with respect to only one of them. You'd have to resort to `//@ slice pragma expr b;` for the first one or `//@ slice pragma expr c;` for the second one.

More generally, slicing criteria are cumulative: the more criteria you give, the more code will be kept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That helps a lot. Is there also a possibility to slice for all assertions of the global scope rather than for specific functions?

Comment: @Paddre Technically, there's no such thing as an assertion at global scope: they are tied to a statement. Do you mean all assertions of all functions in the program? If yes, you can use the shortcut `@all` instead of naming all the functions as a comma-separated list argument of `-slice-assert`

Comment: The latter nailed it. Thx :-)